# How to print 0 to 9 digits without using any digit in our code?

Tags: c

Recently, I found a problem on hackerearth that is how to print 726 without any digits. This is the link to question [:https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/college/r1/golf/726/](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/college/r1/golf/726/)

I have solved this with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("%d",('\e'*'\e')-('\r'-'\n'));

}
```

but since I found this question interesting, I would love to print every single digit without use of any digit. So, I want to print 0 to 9 all in a new line without using any digit with the help of unicodes. How could I do that?

Comment: http://ideone.com/d4Y9xg

Comment: Thanks for the help @BLUEPIXY . but I don't want simple approach . I want to use unicode.

Comment: What does Unicode you mean one line for each number? E.g `printf("%d\n", !'a');` for `0` , `printf("%d\n", !!'a');` for `1` and (+) so on.

Comment: `printf("%d", snprintf(NULL,0,"abcde"));` for `5`. Is not this acceptable?

Comment: `'\e'` and the other characters may map to different values than you expect on some implementations. Not [all the world's a vax](http://catb.org/jargon/html/V/vaxocentrism.html).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `printf("%d", snprintf(NULL,0,"abcde"));` uses the digit `0`.

Comment: @chux you are right! `0` replace with `!'a'`.

Comment: Or replace `0` with (iso646.h) `false??!??! not true`.

Comment: `'\e'` doesn't even exist in standard C. `'\t'*'\t'*'\t'` would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ZERO ('a' - 'a')
#define ONE ((int)(sizeof (char)))
#define TWO (ONE + ONE)
#define THREE (TWO + ONE)
#define SIX (TWO * THREE)
#define SEVEN (SIX + ONE)

int main(void) {
    printf("%d%d%d\n", SEVEN, TWO, SIX);
    /* Assume C99 and implicit return 0; */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    for(int n = !&n; snprintf(NULL, !&n, "%d", n)==!!&n; printf("%d\n", n++));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's countless of ways to write obscure, nonsense C code. One example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  for(size_t i=!"A string."; i<sizeof("A string."); i++)
    printf("%zu ", i);
}
```

Or, more creatively, in pure standard C:

```
??= include"stdio.h"

#define wtf(x,...) x%:%: nt ma ##x %:%:n(vo ##x %:%:d) ??<for(x %:%:nt x =(+ __LINE__??!??!\
+__LINE__) +- !!"WTF"; x<=__LINE__; +i++)??<\
pr ##x %:%:nt %:%:f((char[])<%'%','d',' ',!"WTF"??>,-+-x);%>??>



                                   wtf(i)
```

Comment: @Colin__s Trigraphs are sooo 1995 though. All the hipsters use digraphs.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  char ch='/';
  while(ch!=':')
  { 
      if(isdigit(ch))
      {
        printf("%c\n ",ch);
      }
      ch++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Rather than `'/'; ':'`, could start/end at `CHAR_MN,CHAR_MAX`

Comment: it will generate appropriate answer that he wants @NIKUNJ KHOKHAR

Answer (score -2):

You can check the values of [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) an use the char with %d placeholder for extract the number.
E.g. :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char a='H';
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```